# Applying Tannery's theorem to generalised hypergeometric functions

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence, hypergeometric-function

I am thinking about applying Tannery's theorem to some generalised hypergeometric functions, which seems to be a standard method to derive various formulæ. For example,
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to+\infty}{}_3F_2\Big(
\begin{matrix}
a,b,c-n, \\ a-b+1,a+c+1+n
\end{matrix}
;1\Big),
\end{eqnarray}
To apply Tannery's theorem, we need to find a sequence $(d_k)$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
|a_k| \leq d_k, \quad
\sum_{k=0}^\infty d_k < +\infty
\end{eqnarray}
where $a_k$ is defined as the summand of the ${}_3F_2$ above,
\begin{eqnarray}
a_k:=\frac{(a)_k(b)_k(c-n)_k}{k!(a-b+1)_k(a+c+1+n)_k}
\end{eqnarray}
I would like to know concrete examples of such $(d_k)$.